# Bug in MAMP/MYSQL setup

Tags: mysql, terminal, mamp

I made a .profile file with the following code in it:

```
PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
export PATH
```

I still can't get the "mysql" command to work or to get the MYSQL admin to work. I feel like this is also contributing to not being able to view any of the PHP scripts I've written to test. I also tried getting to the specific 'htdocs' folder for my MAMP directory and when I did ls -a in the terminal, this is what I got back:

```
.
..
.DS_Store
Akamai
Indiana Jones and the Fate of Atlantis.app
Portal.app
```

Obviously, I have more than just those applications. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to turn off the native apache server to get a proper connection on the right port, and this is what I retyped in the .profile folder (which I renamed to .bash_profile) :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
```

Once I did this, and stopped apache in the terminal with:

```
sudo apachectl stop
```

Everything worked!